# Cannot go to localhost using Firefox

Tags: firefox, localhost

I'm using Windows XP SP3 and xampp and cannot access localhost files using Firefox 26.  What I got is 500 Internal Server Error.

After writing localhost address inside address bar and pressing Enter I get the following inside the address bar:

```
http://search.smartaddressbar.com/web?s=localhost%2Fxx%2Fmc&application_hash=e95e91cc646c2564414b02b64aa894ed
```

It works fine in Chrome.

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a Firefox redirect caused by malware and/or an extension. I suggest you check your extensions and find the smartaddressbar.com redirect. If you can't find such an extension or removing it doesn't solve the issue I suggest running a malware scanner. I recommend:

[superantispyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/)
[malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)

*Update*

Additional steps can include checking Add/Remove Programs and find Smart Address Bar. Following this it is suggested you restart Firefox through the troubleshooter menu.

[Source](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/search-smartaddressbar-com-removal/)

Comment: Matthew, there is no smartaddresbar in the list of installed addons or plugins.
Superantispyware found some critical items and removed them. After restarting the system, problem with Firefox/localhost remains.

I noteced, if that matters, when I copy the address from Chrome and want to paste it inside Firefox addressbar (or Paste and Go) - nothing happens. An old address remains inside.

Have you any idea, pls?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include some other suggestions and a link to a recommendation to remove this hijack.

Comment: Matthew, finally solved using reset firefox button. You really helped me so much. Thanks a lot four your patience.